# Unity seems to restart my running animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

My animation seems to start, and then restart after it starts. I have two scripts. This one is attached to the player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 4.5f;
    public float jumpForce = 5f; // Set an appropriate value for jumpForce
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Animator animator;
    private float idleTimer = 1f; // Make the animation start when scene starts
    private bool isMoving = false;

    void Update()
    {
        // Rotate the player to match the camera's rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);

        // Move the player in the forward direction based on the input
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = (transform.forward * verticalInput * speed) * Time.deltaTime;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement);
        isMoving = Mathf.Abs(verticalInput) > 0;
        Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(verticalInput) > 0);

        animator.SetFloat("Running", Mathf.Abs(verticalInput * speed));
        animator.SetBool("Idle", !isMoving);
        Debug.Log(animator.GetFloat("Running"));
    }
}
```

And this one is attached to the Cinemachine camera (To make the camera only move when dragging) (Probably not relevant):

```
using Cinemachine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookOnDrag : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineFreeLook cam;
    public float xSpeed;
    public float ySpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        xSpeed = cam.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed;
        ySpeed = cam.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            cam.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = xSpeed;
            cam.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = ySpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            cam.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
            cam.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Footage:
https://wonderful-crostata-d022dc.netlify.app/2023-06-16-20-14-29.mkv

Also, I am not actually sure what the actual problem is, and I don't know the a

Answer (score 0):

```
animator.SetBool("Idle", !isMoving);
```

You are setting the Bool value every update by inverting the isMoving value without checking for any condition. If your Transition to idle is based on this, you should be constantly switching in and off.

Comment: Yes the flag sea a bit redundant .. but actually `isMoving` wouldn't change every frame .. it stays true while you are running anyway